# Evaluating integral of product of two periodic functions

Tags: integration

Is there a straight-forward way to evaluate an integral of the following type?

$\int_0^T e^{ik\frac{2\pi}{T} t} f(t) dt, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Here $f(t)$is also a periodic function of period $T$ (although it some situations it may not be exactly $T$, so if it's possible to solve it without using this fact, even better).

[Edit] Maybe useful to know, $\int f(t) dt$ is known.

---

Some background: I am trying to implement an algorithm for the continuation of cycles of a dynamical system and this equation pops up for the phase condition. For the numerical implementation it would be really nice to replace this integral with some analytic expression.

Comment: What does "may not be exactly $T$" mean?

Comment: $f(t)$ will usually be the derivative of an approximate solution of the cycle. The true cycle has period T, the approximate solution will have approximately the same period. But in other derivations it is actually assumed that the periods are exactly equal. This will result in a numerical error, but given that the approximation is good, the error is small

Answer (score 1):

If we substitute the Fourier expansion for $f(t)$ and assume that the periods are exactly the same, the integral vanishes *unless* $k=0$. In my case I sum over all possible $k$, so that is what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried computing $\alpha (T) =e^{ik2\pi/T}$ and an integration by parts with $\alpha(T)^t$ ?

Comment: Yes, but I just get a different integral right? I would like to get an expression without integral

Comment: I have the integral of $f(t)$ wrt $t$ though, added that in the question